# Code effects business rules for windows application

Tags: codeeffects

Can I use code-effects business rules for Windows Applications or Console applications?
I want to define the rules using the rule editor but want to execute those rules as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if you are OK referencing System.Web assembly in your project.